# Household inverter/battery array to supplement generator

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, inverter, generator, ups

I live in an area that's prone to occasional power outages (e.g., ice bringing down trees in the winter, hay landing on and blowing out transformers in the summer). Last summer we had a standby generator installed (22kw with ATS) because I was tired of pulling out my smaller (10kw) portable unit and dealing with significantly reduced capacity when called on. I've tested it a few times since, and it works great (after about a 10 second delay to start up).

I also had a Sense energy monitor installed at the same time so that I could get a sense of what our actual draw is at any given time. I was concerned that our heat pump (5 ton) might pull too much power. In general, it seems fine. But now that colder temperatures have arrived and it's doing its defrost cycle occasionally, I'm seeing large draws that would definitely exceed the capacity of the generator (as much as 30kw total draw for maybe 3 minutes at a time once or so a day).

The quickest solution would be to just turn off the HVAC when the generator fires up and switch to using in-room portable heaters. I could probably run 10 (way more than I need) of those + the rest of the house with no trouble on that 22kw.

Alternatively, I'm pondering the idea of building a large battery array as a way to maintain continuous power. I'm thinking that it could do two things:

1. Bridge the 10 second gap in coverage for the generator to spin up.
2. Augment the power supplied by the generator to cover the short time periods of high draw.

I'm looking at something like this: https://www.aimscorp.net/50kw-50-000-watt-dc-to-ac-pure-sine-power-inverter-charger-384-vdc.html + a 36 battery array of relatively low AH (optimized for high current rather than duration of coverage).

That's more money than I want to spend and more capacity than I need, but the next smallest inverter from AIMS is 30kw which wouldn't cover a worst-case scenario of HVAC defrost + water heater + dryer or whatever during that 10 second window + supplementary for a few minutes to cover the insufficient generator capacity to ride out the defrost cycle.

Is this a thing that people do? Or is this a dumb idea? I have an electrician who I work with who's generally willing to pursue my ideas, but this is much more complex than I've asked him to consider in the past and I thought I'd run it by you folks before I take it to him.

I also have a 4kw PV array and grid-tied inverter. But that's pretty automatic and probably not too complicated to deal with (although it does tend to act funny when the generator is running - it resets and takes like 5-10 minutes to come back online as the generator adjusts to load).

[image: iComfort Display]

[image: Sense Monitor]

Comment: Have you checked that your heat pump's measured peak power is within the specified range? Before doing anything else, I would confirm that the 30 kW peak power is within the expected range, rather than from a malfunction. It seems quite large for a residential unit, even for only 3 three minutes.

Comment: The heat pump itself is probably contributing about 22kw during the defrost. This morning it came on right as I was waking up and the total draw jumped from 3kw to 25kw.

The max of about 30kw was probably during a period when other stuff was running (water heater or dryer, etc.)